# How to write Snowflake query to fetch data from JSON array?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am learning `Snowflake`. I have a record where one column has JSON data with array. I want to query this array and populate results if it matches the condition.

i.e., Here, `line_items` is an array.

```
select top 100 line_items
from json_table.json_column
```

Record 1:

```
[
  {
    "description": "washer",
    "sourceSupplier": "AMAZON",
    "supplier": "AMAZON"
  },
  {
    "description": "dryer",
    "sourceSupplier": "EBAY",
    "supplier": "EBAY"
  },
  {
    "description": "heater",
    "sourceSupplier": "AliBaba",
    "supplier": "AliBaba"
  }
]
```

Record 2:

```
[
  {
    "description": "heater",
    "sourceSupplier": "AliBaba",
    "supplier": "AliBaba"
  }
]
```

Now, I want to write a query which looks into this array and fetch the results where `sourceSupplier` contains `Amazon` or `EBay`. So in above example, I should just get `record 1`.

My queries:

- Using `array_contains`. This doesn't bring any result back + I don't know how to add 2 conditions in contains.

```
select top 100 line_items
from json_table.json_column
where array_contains('Amazon' ::variant, line_items )
order by _TS desc
```

- Using  `LATERAL FLATTEN`. This returns the same result as my first query.

```
select top 100 line_items
from json_table.json_column
,LATERAL FLATTEN (input => json_table.json_column.line_items)
order by _TS desc
```

Another using `FLATTEN`: This returns nothing.

```
SELECT
  top 100 VALUE:sourceSupplier
FROM
  json_table.json_column,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(input => json_table.json_column:sourceSupplier) as VALUE
```

Using `table`: No results

```
SELECT
  top 100 VALUE:sourceSupplier
FROM
  json_table.json_column as S,
  table(flatten(S.line_items,'root')) as VALUE
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You want to flatten the array first and laterally apply that to each line_item before parsing key values

```
select distinct a.*, b.value:sourceSupplier::varchar as sourceSupplier
from json_table a, lateral flatten(input=>line_items) b
where -- filter as you wish
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending a day, I ended up following this route.

```
SELECT
   tableName.stock_number AS StockNumber, 
   VALUE:sourceSupplier::string AS Supplier, 
   VALUE:itemUpdateDateTime::date as ItemUpdatedDate, 
   tableName.created_date_time::date AS CreatedDateTime
FROM
  json_table as tableName,
  LATERAL FLATTEN(input => line_items) as VALUE
WHERE (CONTAINS(Supplier, 'AMAZON') OR CONTAINS(Supplier, 'EBAY')) AND CreatedDateTime > '2023-08-31' -- to fetch data prior to this date.
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tableName.stock_number ORDER BY tableName.stock_number) = 1 -- To get unique stockNumber
```